# How to use father's method with son's variable in java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

since the content of my code is very long, i'll try to keep it abstract.
so, I have an abstract father, containing methods that are applicable for all its sons.

```
abstract class a {
 protected final void a_method() {
  ...do stuff
 }
}
```

and I have another two classes that extends a

```
class b extends a {
  static int _int = 3;
}
```

and also,

```
class c extends a {
  static int _int = 2;
}
```

So as you see, all my b's always have the same static _int variable, and all my c's always have the same _int variable as well. 
The method a_method() is exactly the same code for both sons, just using the son's variable.
can I avoid the duplication of code?
since my variable is static, I cant declare it in `a` because it needs to be different for each son's class (different content for each extending class)

Comment: *parent* and *child* sounds better :)

Comment: Have you tried in `Class b` to `this._int = 3;`

Comment: Does it **need** to be static?

Comment: @user2860598 If you declare it in Class a and change it in any one of the subclass using **this** as you suggest then changes will be reflected in all other subclasses.

Comment: @Chris Yes, otherwise it would be easier as i could declare it in parent and override in children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I use for this case would be that a, b, and c all implement an Interface that declares `int getTheVariable()`.  This method is abstract in a.

Then `getTheVariable()` is used in `a`.  The value returned is determined by the concrete implementation.

```
interface Foo {
     int getTheVariable();
}

abstract class A implements Foo {
    abstract int getTheVariable();
    int doSomeWork() {
        return 5 * getTheVariable();
        }
    }

class B extends A implements Foo {
    int getTheVariable() { return 3; }
    }

class C extends A implements Foo {
    int getTheVariable() { return 2; }
    }
```

I didn't try to compile that, it ought to be close.

Now the 'father' class, A, can supply the main code but use the values from B and C as needed.  The values could be static in those classes.

Comment: thank you. that seems simple. I tought perhaps there's some more implicit way to get it. a virtual method is ok too I guess

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is to use an abstract method in the class A to return the subclass int value.

```
abstract class a {
    protected final void a_method() {
       int i = getValue();

       ...do stuff
    }

    protected abstract int getValue();

}
```

And after in your subclass

```
class b extends a {
    static int _int = 3;

    protected int getValue() {
       return _int;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static means the variable belongs to a Class rather than an individual instances. Since your requirement is the static variable to have different values in both classes your problem will not be counted as code duplication.

If it was not static you could define the variable in a class and then initialize it in the b Class and C class constructor.